# Erro 403 Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cpanel

Após subir o site feito em asp.net mvc, ao tentar acessar , eu tenho este erro, existe alguma configuração necessária  a ser feita?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde você hospedou seu site? Dizendo o nome acho que o pessoal pode ajudar mais!

Comment: http://www.vbmahospedagem.com.br/ eu hospedei aqui, a hospedagem até que é boa mais o suporte "o". muito a desejar.

Comment: olha, tem a [somee](https://somee.com/default.aspx) que é otima também. Só que é ingles, a forma free dela é muito boa, eu já usei... O chato de ser free é que tem o banner de propaganda da empresa.. Você ta usando plano free ou pago?

Comment: meu plano é pago

Comment: Eu estou buscando uma solução para este erro